# how to use dynamic data in java script from a file?

Tags: javascript, python, json, database

I have a  python script running and generating  data  continously. i need that data  to modify object in javascript .  is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: You need to quickly expand this question with example code and data unless you want it to be closed in a few minutes. Data cannot modify an object. Some process might

Comment: Yes, there probably is, but have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming you want to use the object on the client side** - You can use the python script to create a JSON object that is written to file that can be retrieved by an AJAX call. Using JavaScript you can read the data provided by the JSON object and use it.

To do this you will have to take the following steps:

1. Create a JSON object using Python - this resource should guide you how to do that: 
   https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html
2. save the object in a file ex: data.json
3. In your client side script - make an Ajax call and request the file data.json. Example:

`//using jQuery but you can do this using JavaScript only too
 $.getJSON('data.json',function(data){
 //enter your code to use the data here
 });`

Render the data using .innerHTML or jQuery's .html() feature.

Links to AJAX tutorials:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: w3schools are not considered a quality reference. There are many better references out there.